# What is a word/phrase/archetype for someone / something that is frequently misidentified

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase for someone/something that is frequently misidentified?

Or a cultural archetype/example --- I have a vague memory of some literary or TV character who's a fugitive criminal and can't be identified by witnesses except in an inconsistent manner ("He's short and slim, with brown hair!" "He's a big burly blond guy!" "I didn't see her clearly except for her eyes and smile!")

other examples:

- the blue/gold dress https://www.wired.com/2015/02/science-one-agrees-color-dress/
- seals / sea lions are commonly confused

Comment: Chameleon. Often people who can easily change how other people perceive them are called chameleons in spy stories. But that’s a metaphor.